# Python- Read two lists from a file as a list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists in a .txt file, I need python to read the file and create two separate lists under a variable name. At the moment I can read the data and split this into two variables ([:pointer] and [pointer:]) but Python interprets these as strings. Any way I can get these interpreted as lists without the formatting being broken (I have tried .split() and list() and these both break the formatting.

What I have in the file:

```
["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I need this to be read into two variables so that it is like this:

```
List1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]
List2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

This is so that I can use methods such as:

```
List1[3] = "D"
```

If you could help me with this I would be really grateful. So, I just need the two lists which are in the .txt file to be read into Python as two separate lists.

Comment: What format are these lines? JSON? Python? How ist the  file created?

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve this via using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
import ast

with open('/path/to/my_file.txt') as f:
    my_list = map(ast.literal_eval, f.readlines())
    #                 ^ to convert *list like string* to `list` object
```

Now you may access the individual list using the index as:

```
>>> my_list[0]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
>>> my_list[1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

In case if it is *must* to store it into variable *(though I will strongly suggest to access the values based on index)*, you may unwrap the returned list into variables as:

```
list1, list2 = map(ast.literal_eval, f.readlines()) 

# Note: Number of variables used to unwrap the list should be 
#       equal to count of nested lists.
```